# Ruby + Option parser

Tags: ruby

I am learning option parsing in ruby by referring [this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) and [this](http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/optionparser.htm). This is my test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require "optparse"

options = {}

optparse = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Learning Option parsing in Ruby"

  opts.on("-i", "--ipaddress", "IP address of the server") do |ipaddr|
    options[:ipaddress] =  ipaddr
  end

    opts.on("-u", "--username", "username to log in") do |user|
      options[:username] = user
    end

    opts.on("-p", "--password", "password of the user") do |pass|
      options[:password] = pass
    end
end

optparse.parse!

puts "the IPaddress is #{options[:ipaddress]}" if options[:ipaddress]
puts "the username is #{options[:username]}" if options[:username]
puts "the password is #{options[:password]}" if options[:password]
```

My intention is to print the opton that I am passing to the script. However, it doens't print the option that I pass, instead just says `true`:

```
# ruby getops.rb  --ipaddress 1.1.1.1
the IPaddress is true
# ruby getops.rb  --username user1
the username is true
# ruby getops.rb  --password secret
the password is true
```

Where am I going wrong? I tried with the short options as well , but the result is same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# Mandatory argument.
  opts.on("-r", "--require LIBRARY",
          "Require the LIBRARY before executing your script") do |lib|
    options.library << lib
  end
```

I found that by your first link. Pay attention on "--require LIBRARY".

Comment: correct. I has already read what you posted. Just that I did not pay attention to it.

Answer (score 7):

What if you change it to:

```
opts.on("-i", "--ipaddress IPADDRESS", "IP address of the server") do |ipaddr|
  options[:ipaddress] =  ipaddr
end
```

Note the `IPADDRESS` in the second argument.

Comment: +1. thanks. both the answers are correct. Hence I will accept the one by @Sergey which was posted earlier in chronological order.

Comment: You're welcome, although I think my answer was poster earlier. ;)

Comment: I would - for sake of convention - , use the same wording in the description ("IPADDRESS") as in the long parameter statement.